# Xcode 9.2 crashing on successful build with react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native application which was working fine this morning but now I can't get it to build at all. I ran into some major linking errors today, and was getting build errors for a while. I finally managed to get the build to succeed after abandoning manual linking and using a combination of `react-native link` and `pod install`. But now when the build succeeds Xcode itself crashes. The simulator is opening but Xcode crashes before it can even try to install the new build. I have never seen anything like it before with Xcode.

```
react-native 0.51.0
react 16.0.0
node 7.8.0
Xcode 9.2
Cocoapods 1.4.0
```

Error report:

> Process:               Xcode [3747] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   Xcode Version:               9.2 (13772) App Item ID:
>   497799835 App External ID:       825038102 Code Type:
>   X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:
>   Xcode [3747] User ID:               502
>
> Date/Time:             2018-03-31 20:10:21.783 -0500 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.13.3 (17D102) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
>   D8F23055-EFF7-4CD7-5BEE-671DADA76EF5
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 640 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        18  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue:
>   -[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:]_block_invoke_3
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 9C40b UNCAUGHT
>   EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): ***
>   -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0] UserInfo: (null) Hints:
>   Backtrace:   0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)   1
>   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)   2
>   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)   3
>   _CFThrowFormattedException (in CoreFoundation)   4   -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] (in CoreFoundation)   5   +[NSDictionary
>   dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] (in CoreFoundation)   6
>   __68-[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:]_block_invoke.807 (in
>   IDEiOSSupportCore)   7   __38-[DVTFuture(DVTFutureAdditions)
>   then:]_block_invoke_2 (in DVTFoundation)   8   __44-[DVTFuture
>   _internalSetState:result:error:]_block_invoke.207 (in DVTFoundation)   9   -[DVTFuture setState:result:error:] (in DVTFoundation)  10
>   __54-[DVTFuture trackFuture:progress:cancel:result:error:]_block_invoke.266 (in
>   DVTFoundation)  11   -[DVTFuture observeFinish:] (in DVTFoundation) 
>   12   -[DVTFuture trackFuture:progress:cancel:result:error:] (in
>   DVTFoundation)  13   -[DVTFuture trackFuture:] (in DVTFoundation)  14 
>   __38-[DVTFuture(DVTFutureAdditions) then:]_block_invoke_2 (in DVTFoundation)  15   __44-[DVTFuture
>   _internalSetState:result:error:]_block_invoke.207 (in DVTFoundation)  16   -[DVTFuture setState:result:error:] (in DVTFoundation)  17
>   __54-[DVTFuture trackFuture:progress:cancel:result:error:]_block_invoke.266 (in
>   DVTFoundation)  18   __44-[DVTFuture
>   _internalSetState:result:error:]_block_invoke.207 (in DVTFoundation)  19   -[DVTFuture setState:result:error:] (in DVTFoundation)  20
>   -[DVTFuture succeedWithResult:] (in DVTFoundation)  21   __68-[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:]_block_invoke_4 (in
>   IDEiOSSupportCore)  22   __DVTCreateSingleCallBlock_block_invoke (in
>   DVTFoundation)  23   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib) 
>   24   _dispatch_block_invoke_direct (in libdispatch.dylib)  25
>   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)  26   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)  27   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)  28   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)  29   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)  30   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)  31   _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)  32   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)  33   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)   abort() called
>
> Application Specific Signatures: NSInvalidArgumentException
>
> Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff50ccafcb __exceptionPreprocess + 171 1   DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000107063a5c DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 274 2
>   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff77980c76
>   objc_exception_throw + 48 3   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff50d0c264 _CFThrowFormattedException + 202 4   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff50bce6c2 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 322 5   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff50bce54b +[NSDictionary
>   dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59 6   IDEiOSSupportCore
>   0x0000000119710f51 __68-[DVTiPhoneSimulator
>   launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:]_block_invoke.807 + 108
>   7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fbd909
>   __38-[DVTFuture(DVTFutureAdditions) then:]_block_invoke_2 + 104 8   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fbb5c3 __44-[DVTFuture
>   _internalSetState:result:error:]_block_invoke.207 + 89 9   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fbb8d9 -[DVTFuture
>   setState:result:error:] + 199 10  DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000106fbca1a __54-[DVTFuture
>   trackFuture:progress:cancel:result:error:]_block_invoke.266 + 119 11 
>   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fb9565 -[DVTFuture
>   observeFinish:] + 277 12  DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000106fbc7e8 -[DVTFuture
>   trackFuture:progress:cancel:result:error:] + 331 13  DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000106fbd0a8 -[DVTFuture trackFuture:] + 42 14  DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000106fbd927 __38-[DVTFuture(DVTFutureAdditions)
>   then:]_block_invoke_2 + 134 15  DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000106fbb5c3 __44-[DVTFuture
>   _internalSetState:result:error:]_block_invoke.207 + 89 16  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fbb8d9 -[DVTFuture
>   setState:result:error:] + 199 17  DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000106fbca1a __54-[DVTFuture
>   trackFuture:progress:cancel:result:error:]_block_invoke.266 + 119 18 
>   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fbb5c3 __44-[DVTFuture
>   _internalSetState:result:error:]_block_invoke.207 + 89 19  DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106fbb8d9 -[DVTFuture
>   setState:result:error:] + 199 20  DVTFoundation
>   0x0000000106fbbb0a -[DVTFuture succeedWithResult:] + 31 21 
>   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000119710abf
>   __68-[DVTiPhoneSimulator launchSimulatedExecutable:launchService:error:]_block_invoke_4 + 70 22
>   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106f8606d
>   __DVTCreateSingleCallBlock_block_invoke + 133 23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff78536d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 24  libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x00007fff78549333 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317 25 
>   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001070b9a4f
>   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 806 26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7853e591 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 27 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff78536d50
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8 28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff78549e76 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 472 29 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff785416cb
>   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 703 30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff78538941 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 515 31 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff785386ed
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 101 32  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff787fb1ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387 33 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff787fac4d start_wqthread
>   + 13
>
> Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff786b67c2 mach_msg_trap + 10 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff786b5cdc mach_msg + 60 2
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff50c46575
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff50c458c7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1783 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff50c44f43 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483 5   com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff4ff5ce26 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286 6
>   com.apple.HIToolbox               0x00007fff4ff5cb96
>   ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613 7   com.apple.HIToolbox
>     0x00007fff4ff5c914 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter +
>   64 8   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff4e227f5f _DPSNextEvent
>   + 2085 9   com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff4e9bdb4c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044 10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit               0x0000000107672f9a -[DVTApplication
>   nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 390 11 
>   com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff4e21cd6d -[NSApplication run]
>   + 764 12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4e1ebf1a NSApplicationMain + 804 13  libdyld.dylib
>     0x00007fff78570115 start + 1
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff786b67c2
>   mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff786b5cdc mach_msg + 60 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
>     0x00007fff50c46575 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 341 3
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff50c458c7 __CFRunLoopRun +
>   1783 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff50c44f43
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483 5   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff52d16c16 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
>   6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase         0x00000001197c9917
>   +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 217 7   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff52d24ee8 __NSThread__start**
>   + 1197 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00007fff787fb6c1 _pthread_body + 340 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00007fff787fb56d _pthread_start + 377 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff787fac5d thread_start + 13

The error report goes on and on but there wasn't anything that seemed relevant in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had overwritten some files as part of my troubleshooting and accidentally deleted my projects bundle identifier. Resetting that made everything work again.